# Segmentation algorithm A4 vs A8 for exploring neighbours

Tags: pixel

I'm implementing the region growing algorithm and I want to know if it's better to explore the neighbours of the pixels with a connectivity A4 or A8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that depends on the case, but usually A8 is better as it explores the diagonals as well...